# Pandas calling partial row data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

I have the following data in a column:

```
Company Name
Company Name\Cortana Place\rBaton Rouge, LA 70815 
Some Product Company\r1Highway 21\rMadis

df = pd.read_csv(csv_cropped_tabula, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

when I call `df['Company Name'][0]` or `df['Company Name'][1]`

I am getting back only following data

```
rBaton Rouge, LA 70815
r1Highway 21\rMadis
```

I dont understand why is it bringing back the partial data not full line

```
Company Name\Cortana Place\rBaton Rouge, LA 70815
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's parsing the embedded commas as separators, it looks like you only have a single column so you can tell it to only load that column and pass `lineterminator='\n'`:

```
In[86]:
t="""Company Name
Company Name\Cortana Place\rBaton Rouge, LA 70815 Some Product
Company\r1Highway 21\rMadi"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), usecols=[0], lineterminator='\n')
df

Out[85]: 
                                        Company Name
0  Company Name\Cortana Place\rBaton Rouge, LA 70...
1                         Company\r1Highway 21\rMadi
```

Here I tell `pandas` to only load the first column `usecols=[0]`, additionally it's reading the `\r` as carriage returns so we can override this and tell it to look specifically for `\n` as the line terminator

If we now look at the first row, we can see it's all there:

```
In[87]:
df['Company Name'].iloc[0]

Out[87]: 'Company Name\\Cortana Place\rBaton Rouge'
```